# Need Honeywell dolphin 9700 Emulator

Tags: pocketpc

For my project earlier we were using Honeywell Dolphin 7900 and for its emulator we were using Pocket PC 2003 device emulator which comes default with visual studio 2008. Now we have switched to  Honeywell dolphin 9700 device. Now the problem is there are few UI issues coming up and for debugging i need corresponding emulator. I tried using windows mobile 6.5 emulator which can be downloaded from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=20686a1d-97a8-4f80-bc6a-ae010e085a6e

But i was not able to reproduce the UI issues there. The .NET framework used is 3.5 for both PDA. Newer PDA has windows mobile 6.5 installed. Can anyone help me to find the exact emulator for  Honeywell dolphin 9700 device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by using windows mobile 6.5 vga emulator. This was the only emulator from which the UI issues were reproducible

Answer (score 0):

We are using the Dolphin 9700 for development as well, but have not found anything beyond the Windows emulator.

If you need different settings based on if the device is running or if the emulator is running, we have set up a compile variable `IsDevice` in the Advanced Compile Options; if we are debugging on the device, we set `IsDevice` to true and if not, we set it to false.

```
#If IsDevice Then
 //do code
#Else
 //do code
#End If
```

Comment: hi,  The issue was solved by using windows mobile 6.5 vga emulator. This was the only emulator from which the UI issues were reproducible.